# cookie in cookie less domain

Tags: cookies

I have set up a cdn for my site and I use it for css, js, and images.

The site serves only those files

My problem is that with the page speed plugin in firefox 
for my image requests I see a cookie

Cookie fc=fcVal=7985951017741594560

does any one know where it comes from ?

Thanks

Comment: Could it be a something injected by the load balancer? What CDN service are you using?

Comment: Have you tried clearing cookies? The Page Speed plugin could well be showing the cookie you are sending to the server, not the server's own cookie-setting response.  Looking for fcval it seems to be set by Godaddy's domain parking pages (perhaps other pages...but the thing in common seems like Godaddy).  So if you visited your cookie domain when it was just a Godaddy parking page, the cookie would be set in your browser, and revisiting it later without clearing cookies would result in resending that very same cookie back in all image requests.

Comment: By the way - try using the "Net" tab of Firebug to see if there are cookies sent in the response, or just the request

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ben

I have cleared my cache and the cookie did not come back